# Is there a special name for functors from a category C to a subcategory of C?

Tags: category-theory, terminology, definition

Is there a special name for functors from a category $C$ to a subcategory $S$ of $C$ where $S \ne C$?

I'm using $\ne$ pretty informally above.  I'd be happy with anything that reasonably captures the intuition.

Comment: They are endofunctors.

Comment: True, but endofunctors map a category back onto itself.  I was wondering if there's a term for something strictly more specific.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand when one category is a "subcategory" of another category. These aren't generally "sets", and some authors would dispense with the objects altogether and keep only arrows.

Comment: I've updated the question.  I'm interested in the case where $\hom(S)$ is a strict subset of $\hom(C)$.

Comment: I don't even know the answer for discrete categories, i.e.: How is a map $X \to Y$ called when $Y \subseteq X$? Is there a special name at all?